# MySQL Query return duplicate rows (No duplicates in table)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to MySQL, I wrote this query

```
SELECT 
        r.id as rID,
        r.title as rTitle,
        r.researcherName as rName,
        r.volumeID as rVolID,
        r.views as rViews,
        r.downloads as rdowns,
        vol.date as volDate,
        vol.title as volTitle,
        vol.versionID as verID,
        ver.title as verTitle
        FROM journalsResearches AS r 
        INNER JOIN  versions as ver
        INNER JOIN  volumes as vol
        ON r.volumeID = vol.id
        AND r.volumeID = 12
        ORDER BY r.views DESC
```

and expected result was 1 row and for some reason, this row has been duplicated as a result and still one row in table

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You're missing the `ON` condition for the `versions` table.

Comment: You're getting a cross product with every row in `versions`, the results have different `verTitle`.

Comment: There is no different title, the `researches` table has just one row.
I'm also tried to add `ON` condition for the `versions` table, but the query return 3 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a condition on the join with the 'versions' table, so your query might actually be returning one row per row in 'versions'.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the query by rearranging tables in `JOIN` statement and adding `ON` condition on `versions`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with rearranging tables in JOIN statement and adding ON condition on versions

```
SELECT
        r.id as rID,
        r.title as rTitle,
        r.researcherName as rResearcherName,
        r.views as rViews,
        r.downloads as rDownloads,
        vol.id as volID,
        vol.title as volTitle,
        vol.date as volDate,
        ver.id as verID,
        ver.title as verTitle
        FROM
        journalsResearches AS r
        INNER JOIN  volumes as vol 
        INNER JOIN  versions as ver 
        ON r.volumeID = vol.id 
        AND vol.versionID = ver.id 
        AND vol.id = 12
        ORDER BY r.views DESC
```